# error with JiraTestResultReporter with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, junit, jira

I configured Jenkins with JiraTestResultReporter plugin. and I am using selenium testNg test cases and it is able read the test case also. but  I am using JIRA free Trail. I didn't Install JIRA in my jenkins.

```
[xUnit] [INFO] - Starting to record.
[xUnit] [INFO] - Processing JUnit
[xUnit] [INFO] - [JUnit] - 1 test report file(s) were found with the pattern '**/TEST-CallingTestSuite.xml' relative to 'C:\SeleniumTest\workspace\testwithJira' for the testing framework 'JUnit'.
[xUnit] [INFO] - Converting 'C:\SeleniumTest\workspace\testwithJira\test-output\junitreports\TEST-CallingTestSuite.xml' .
[xUnit] [INFO] - Check 'Failed Tests' threshold.
[xUnit] [INFO] - Check 'Skipped Tests' threshold.
[xUnit] [INFO] - Setting the build status to SUCCESS
[xUnit] [INFO] - Stopping recording.
[JiraTestResultReporter] [INFO] Examining test results...
[JiraTestResultReporter] [DEBUG] Build result is SUCCESS

[JiraTestResultReporter] [DEBUG] [JiraTestResultReporter] [INFO] Workspace is C:\SeleniumTest\workspace\testwithJira

[JiraTestResultReporter] [DEBUG] projectKey: TEST
[JiraTestResultReporter] [DEBUG] errorDetails: failure message test
[JiraTestResultReporter] [DEBUG] fullName: CallingTestSuite.failingtestcase
[JiraTestResultReporter] [DEBUG] simpleName: CallingTestSuite
[JiraTestResultReporter] [DEBUG] title: Case Result: failingtestcase
[JiraTestResultReporter] [DEBUG] packageName: (root)
[JiraTestResultReporter] [DEBUG] name: failingtestcase
[JiraTestResultReporter] [DEBUG] className: CallingTestSuite
[JiraTestResultReporter] [DEBUG] failedSince: 88
[JiraTestResultReporter] [DEBUG] status: FAILED
[JiraTestResultReporter] [DEBUG] age: 11
[JiraTestResultReporter] [DEBUG] ErrorStackTrace: 
[JiraTestResultReporter] [DEBUG] affectedFile: 
[JiraTestResultReporter] [DEBUG] ----------------------------
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.json.JSONException: A JSONArray text must start with '[' at 1 [character 2 line 1]
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.json.JSONException: A JSONArray text must start with '[' at 1 [character 2 line 1]
[JiraTestResultReporter] [INFO] Done.
Finished: SUCCESS
```

I configured xUnit plugin for reading the test result . But I am getting an error. The issue is not creating in my JIRA server. Following is the error I am getting.

Do I need to install JIRA with Jenkins? or Can I use this trial version server directly?

Comment: What is the problem if it is not creating the issue in Jira? What is the error you are getting.

Comment: For each failed test case I want to create an issue in JIRA. but while reading the test result am getting the error java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.json.JSONException: A JSONArray text must start with '[' at 1 [character 2 line 1].  So it is not able to create the issue in JIRA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a java application instead of trying with this. 
My application will take the failed test cases from the output of selenium test and create the bug in Jira using Jira Rest API.